# Error de allowed_types al subir un archivo en codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Estoy trabajando con codeigniter en un proyecto en el cual tengo que subir archivos en formato mp3, en mi servidor local funciona bien y todo, pero al momento de subir a un hosting me genera el siguiente error

```
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.
```

Lo cual no entiendo ya que estoy trabajando de forma como me lo especifica en la documentación oficial, aqui dejo el código:

```
public function setAudio()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('cat');
    $file_name = $this->input->post('name');
    $file_size = $this->input->post('size');
    $file_type = $this->input->post('type');
    $file_dur  = $this->input->post('dur');
    $ruta = './assets/archivos/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp3';
    foreach ($this->Categoria_model->getCatById($id) as $key) {
        $config['upload_path'] = './assets/archivos/'.$key;
        $ruta = $ruta.$key.'/'.$file_name;
    }
    if(!file_exists($ruta))
    {
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('files'))
        {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error',$error);
            //echo ' no se pudo subir nada'.$config['upload_path'].', error==>'.$error;
            $result = array('error' => true, 'mens' => $error, 'estado' => 3);
            echo json_encode($result);
        }
        else
        {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $dd = $this->Audio_model->insertAudio($file_name,$ruta,$file_dur,$id,$file_type,$file_size);
            //$estado = $this->Video_model->insertVideo($file_name,$ruta,$file_dur,$id,$file_type,$file_size);
            $result = array('error' => false, 'mens' => 'El archivo '.$file_name.', a sido guardado correctamente.', 'estado' => 1);
            echo json_encode($result);
            //echo 'Nombre=>'.$file_name.', Cat=>'.$key.', peso=>'.$file_size.', tipo=>'.$file_type.', duracion=>'.$file_dur.', ruta ==>'.$ruta.', == dd '.$dd;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result = array('error' => true, 'mens' => 'El archivo se encuentra registrado, por favor seleccione otro', 'estado' => 2);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

En mi servidor local tengo configurado el php 5 y php 7 y en los dos funciona correctamente, pero al montar en el hosting no funciona, el hosting tiene una version de php 7 igual a la que tengo instalada, alguien me puede asesorar de como solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Inicializa tu configuración `$config` correctamente.

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```